I am developing a hololens app.I get error "property _InnerGlowColor already exists in the property sheet with a different type: 2 in boundingbox.cs"
This is the component I use.
I get the following error reported:

error:
Property _InnerGlowColor already exists in the property sheet with a different type: 2
UnityEngine.Material:SetFloatArray (string,single[])
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.BoundingBox:SetMaterials () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@f2323a9b7aec/SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/BoundingBox/BoundingBox.cs:1971)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.BoundingBox:CreateRig () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@f2323a9b7aec/SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/BoundingBox/BoundingBox.cs:1216)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.BoundingBox:OnEnable () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@f2323a9b7aec/SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/BoundingBox/BoundingBox.cs:1239)

And
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.BoundingBox.DestroyRig () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@f2323a9b7aec/SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/BoundingBox/BoundingBox.cs:1361)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.BoundingBox.OnDisable () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@f2323a9b7aec/SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/BoundingBox/BoundingBox.cs:1263)

I tried deleting the shader cache but it didn't work, or turning off some components.

Based on the error messages, it appears that you are using both BoundsControl.cs and BoundingBox.cs. Bounding box is deprecated and replaced by its successor bounds control. If you already have BoundsControl, then remove BoundingBox.
